# Android: How do i set the sub item of the list view?

Tags: android, listview

I am using two String array:

```
String[] crs //Contains an array of Student name's

 String[] crsn  // Contains their roll no's
```

What i intend to do is set the list item value as student name and sub item as the roll no

I am using the following method to display the list view items but it only shows the student name not the sub item.

How can i write the code for displaying the sub items too i.e the Roll no's array.

```
    try {

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, new ArrayList()));
            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            new AddStringTask().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (int i = 0; i < crs.length; i++) {
                publishProgress(crs[i]);
            }
            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            ((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            setSelection(3);

        }
    }
```

I am a beginner in android so plz any suggestion is warmly welcome....Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just use this custom adapter in your Listview creation and then you will write your code in this block...

```
use this code in your activity...

CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
  mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And then here you replace your Layout....

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);// Replace your
                                                            // layout....
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());       
    return convertView;
}

}
```